# make Eclipse slimmer

Tags: eclipse, performance

I am trying to run Eclipse on my netbook to be able to develop for Android.

As you may guess, Eclipse is quite slow and it is not easy to develop effectively.

I am using Linux Ubuntu and I have still 0.5GB of free RAM...the CPU is the bottleneck.

Have you got any tip to slim Eclipse down and make it run faster?

Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following settings may help:

- disable automatic build Project / Build Automatically (unchecked)
- disable automatic refresh in Window / Preferences / General / Workspace / Refresh automatically (unchecked)
- disable animations Window / Preferences / General / Appearance / Enable animations (unchecked)
- disable automatic updates Window / Preferences / Install/Update / Automatic updates / Automatically find... (unchecked)
- disable usage data collector Window / Preferences / Usage Data Collector / enable capture (unchecked)
- turn off unnecessary decorations in Window / Preferences / General / Appearance / Label Decorations

But the best of all, get yourself some more memory, so it won't have to constantly run garbage collection.

Answer (score 4):

Close unnecessary projects.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much indeed, Eugene Kuleshov. This was helpful.

Also, to add to above list, if you do not require automatic activation of auto-complete when . is typed,

- disable auto-activation of content assist in Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Content Assist / Enable auto-activation (unchecked)

You can still hit Ctrl-Space to manually bring up the list of methods for that class when required.